# Trying to run Esplora with existing electrs and bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind, blockchain-explorer, electrum-server

I'm trying to run Esplora on a system that's already running bitcoind and electrs, both of which are working.  Electrs is running on port 60001.

```
echo '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "server.version", "params": ["", "1.4"], "id": 0}' | nc -w 2 localhost 60001
{"id":0,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":["electrs/0.10.1","1.4"]}
```

I did the npm run dist and copied the files from dist/ to my nginx doc root.  The page says:

```
We encountered an error. Please try again later.
```

Electrs has been running for awhile, so I don't think it's a sync problem.  I don't see errors and I'm not sure how to debug what's broken here.  Any ideas on how I can get this going?